# Jump to finally without calling return

Tags: c#

In C# (when using a try / finally) how can I jump to the finally section without calling return.

For example:

```
public bool SomeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        ...
        if (...)
        {
            ---> Jump to finally
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }

        ...

        if (...)
        {
            ---> Jump to finally
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        ...

        if (...)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

How can I force a jump to the finally section (without using return)?

**Edit:**

What I'm trying to do is:

```
public bool SomeMethod(ref string Error)
{
    try
    {
        bool result = false;

        if (...)
            ---> Exit to Finally
        else
            ...

        ...

        if (...)
            ---> Exit to Finally
        else
            ...

        ...

        --> more of the above kind of IFs

        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        ...

        if (!result)
        {
                LogAMessage("");
                ...
                Error = "...";
                ...
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Example in the Delphi you could use Exit.

Comment: Is the purpose of the finally to execute code that has to run *before the return* or *after an exception is thrown*?

Comment: @EricLippert Yes that's the purpose - to run code before the return (and based on the result). Added code above.

Comment: Is the error condition *common* or *rare*?

Comment: Is the point of this method to *compute a Boolean value* or to *produce a side effect*? If the latter, does the Boolean describe whether the side effect happened or not? (The point of these questions is that there is almost certainly a better way to build this function than all that control flow logic you're trying to build. But without understanding what the purpose of the function is, it is hard to say what the right thing to do is.)

Comment: @mas if you call return from within the try block, finally still gets executed.  Try it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a label and [`goto`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx).

However, this seems to suggest that your function is probably not structured well.

In this case, you seem to be using `finally` as a *function* - why not extract that logic into a function of its own?

Comment: how can goto be used when it wants the tag to be available in the same code block?

Comment: Define "block", @MuhammadFaraz - as the code in the link clearly shows it isn't the case.

Comment: I was referring to the question. Block means in the same braces { }. Since finally and try are different code blocks, I am not sure how we can jump from try to finally using goto.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be trying to do this...

Consider re-writing your code in a fashion which means the goto -> finally is not a requirement.

Perhaps pull out the code in the finally block into a method and call it in mulitple places...

**Update**

You can get the desired behaviour from the following:

```
public bool SomeMethod(ref string Error)
{
  bool result = false;
  try
  {
    if (...)
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        result = true;
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
finally
{
    if (!result)
    {
            LogAMessage("");
            ...
            Error = "...";
            ...
    }
}
```

However, to achieve such a thing you should check out the [Delegation Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) for a far cleaner way of achieving this logging.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

- Add a dummy block either inside or outside your try/finally block and use **break**:

  ```
  // dummy block inside
  try {
      do {
          ...
          if (condition)
              break;
          ...
      } while (false);
  } finally {
      ...
  }

  // dummy block outside
  do {
      try {
          ...
          if (condition)
              break;
          ...
      } finally {
          ...
      }
  } while (false);
  ```
- Add a label in front of the finally block and use **goto** (note that using goto in general is not recommended).
- Put your block into a separate method so that you can use **return** without leaving the outer method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider placing this method in a class which implements `IDisposable`.

Then you could invoke this method whilst it is wrapped a `using` statement and will be guaranteed to be cleared up.